# Should intelligence be defined strictly by mathematical ingenuity?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Math is such a strong subject in modern curricula, in modern social aspects and archetypes regarding intelligence, and is often coincided with success in any work of study performed. Can one be "intelligent" if they lack math skills?

That is to say, say I win a million dollars. Am I considered an "accomplishment" due to the fact that I have poor math skills? Or do people generally view those excelling in  math to be "smart" overall?

Like most math geeks (no offence, I am a geek of a different sort) we all know how they are regarded as "brainiacs", "brilliant, gifted kids", etc. But in modern school systems if you get an A you are considered "brilliant", but we know that's all bull stuff.

Point being, has society and humans made math a prerequisite for being deemed "intelligent" overall? Can I be a "smart" person even if I am mediocre with math? Or would I have to be smart with math to be considered or deemed worthy?

Comment: Do we consider doctors 'intelligent'? If so, they often don't have to use very much math. They don't even have to be good at Bayesian inference with respect to the chance of false positives/negatives for medical tests. I don't believe dosage requires significant math. Indeed, doctors need to be good at memorizing, something which mathematicians can be quite _bad_ at.

Comment: @labreuer The activities of [Gerd Gigerenzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerd_Gigerenzer) suggest that medical doctors might be "smarter" (i.e., better, also for the patient's sake) when it comes to statistical inference.

Comment: @aufkag, that article indicates that it is possible to teach 4th graders a way to represent this statistical information in a way that they could "make Bayesian inferences correctly without any outside help". So it seems like doctors may simply be 'cheating' by having access to this 'mental tool'.

Answer (score 4):

As Terence Tao (famous mathematician winner of the Fields Prize) said in his [blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/does-one-have-to-be-a-genius-to-do-maths/):

> Does one have to be a genius to do mathematics?
>   The answer is an emphatic **NO**. In order to make good and useful contributions to mathematics, one does need to [work hard](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/work-hard/), learn one’s field well, learn other fields and tools, ask questions, talk to other mathematicians, and think about the “big picture”. And yes, a reasonable amount of intelligence, patience, and maturity is also required. But one does **not** need some sort of magic “genius gene” that spontaneously generates ex nihilo deep insights, unexpected solutions to problems, or other supernatural abilities.

So we can conclude that a "*genius*" is not related to why a person has a *mathematical ingenuity*, and there are plenty of "*genius*" in other areas such as sports, game developing...etc Thus, *intelligence* cannot be defined by *mathematical ingenuity*.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain the downvote?

Comment: Oops, meant to downvote the question. Sorry. If you could edit your answer (and then change it back to what it is now), I'd be happy to correct my mistake. Unfortunately voters don't get notified when these comments are added to posts. Let me know once you edit so I can retract my vote.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan Why do you want to downvote the answer?

Comment: As I said, I don't. I accidentally downvoted your answer. Now it's fixed.

Comment: Conceding that you don't have to be a genius to do maths does not answer the question, the question is do you have to do maths to be a genius.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, if** we define 'mathematical ingenuity' as:

> Being good at recognizing patterns and manipulating them toward beautiful ends.

When stated this way, the above includes:

- Bach
- Einstein
- Picasso
- Francis Collins
- Admiral Rickover
- Winston Churchill

My point is that life contains an *incredible* amount of pattern-matching that uses no explicit numbers nor symbols recognizable as math equations. Good businessmen understand the patterns of human behavior and are able to make use of that knowledge to make cool things and get lots of money. Good musicians have an innate grasp of the math behind sounds that please our ears, even if they have no idea what group theory is. Biologists made fantastic discoveries without strict equations by being able to reason at a 'fuzzy' level.

We err greatly if we think of mathematics as being restricted to e.g. geometry, calculus, statistics, and probability. Mathematics is merely "the study of patterns". I would argue that anyone of high intelligence is good at some kind of pattern-matching and use.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso was a genius at art; Joyce was a genius at literature; Brahms was a genius at music; Heidegger was a genius at philosophy. None of these people used mathematics (though they might have enjoyed with what little they were acquainted with at school like Yeats), so no, understanding mathematics is not the only indication of genius.

further, intelligence is multi-faceted; some-one may be a genius in mathematics (or some other discipline) but be very ordinary, or even poorer than the average at others.